# Can you use craft: trapmaking instead of disable device?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

I have a character that doesn't have disable device skill, but I took trapmaking for a craft skill can I apply that to disabling just traps or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that character would still need to use the disable device skill.

If you read the Trapmaking guide, you will even find the section about how a trapmaking could  include a bypass into the trap. This bypasses all do need a check different to Craft(trapmaking).

Anyway, some GM may rule that a character with craft in trapmaking would gain a small (+2) synergy bonus for checks to overcome a trap.

Comment: I would probably allow a Trapmaker to disable a trap that _he specifically made_, however, I also agree that he would need Disable Device regarding other traps.